# .NET Remoting : Sometimes returned object is empty, sometimes error as A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly resp

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-remoting, nic

I have a problem with .NET Remoting(VB 2010).
I made a Client/Server application which works fine in Local netowrk. When I run the client outside local network, I get the empty object returned or the error as 'A Connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond 192.168.5.60:9100'

I have the NAT rule on router and windows firewall wont block the application on either side.
The problem is, from client I am connecting to Public IP, the router forwards to the server. Then the next time the client calls to the server's Local IP which is a different network, and the connection fails giving the above error. **Why the Client is connecting to the Server's Local IP on subsequent calls?** Can somebody help me to get this issue solved. 
I dont have any app.config files at both end.
Edit: I don't have any firewall server, just normal setup ROUTER > SERVER(LAN).

### Client Code:

```
Dim URI as string = " tcp://109.120.24.82:8100/FTObj"
RemotingConfiguration.CustomErrorsMode = CustomErrorsModes.Off
tcpChannel = New Tcp.TcpChannel(9100)
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, False)
Dim FTFactoryObj As IFTFactory.IFTFactory = DirectCast(Activator.GetObject(GetType(IFTFactory.IFTFactory), URI), IFTFactory.IFTFactory)
IFTObjC = FTFactoryObj.createFTObj
```

### Server Code:

```
 tcpChannel = New Tcp.TcpChannel(9100)
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(tcpChannel, False)
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(GetType(FTFactory.FTFactory), FTConfig.ServerAppObject, WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton)
```

Comment: The errors that you are seeing have nothing to do with remoting. They are TCP-level errors. You can debug them with telnet.

Comment: No, it has to do someting with Remoting. The host application on server exposes the server's Local IP address to the client, then the client call back to the Local IP instead of Public IP. I guess I am missing some settings.

Comment: Consider this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385815/why-net-remoting-server-cant-send-event-to-internet-clients

Comment: So, that means .NET Remoting cannot be used outside Local network? I dont have events on server that raise on clients, nothing like that. Just the first call goes correct, the second call goes to the Local IP of server(on different network).