# .Net Remoting application not working over Internet

Tags: .net, remoting, .net-remoting

I'm developing my first .Net Remoting application. Every thing was going perfect until
I thought about running my app (Client and Server) over the Internet. Both the client and server have dynamic IPs.

This snippet is from the Client App:

```
//IRemoteFactory fac = (IRemoteFactory)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IRemoteFactory),"http://'localhost':1234/App.soap;
```

The connection fails when I replace `localhost` with the public IP of the router to which the computer (Server) is attached. The connection also fails when I replace `localhost` with a private IP.

So, the question is:

Can I connect to the server by connecting to a public IP and then from it connecting to the private IP, or do I have to do it through a middle service hosted on a third server with static IP? or is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: You should consider the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2385919/1140783

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Remoting instead of a modern API like WCF?

Comment: sttaq => i'm not sure if the problem is with the firewall or with connecting to the local pc

Comment: Scott => Acually there is no specific reason :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Does WCF enables me to connect two local computers together through the internet ? I mean if you advice me to read about it

Comment: WCF is used almost identically as .NET Remoting, only the opening of the connection and the hosting of the service is different. .NET Remoting is considered "Deprecated" and should not be used for new software. I would reccomend looking for tutorials on WCF. (Also what does "*local computers together through the internet*" mean, why would two local computers need to go through the internet to talk to each other? Did you mean two ***remote*** computers together through the internet?)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yes i mean 'two remote computers' ... for example develop an app like the Microsoft Remote Desktop in the windows but against two dynamic ips ... like team viewer do